# Simplest way to translate just date and time

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I have a website running on Drupal 8, it a single language website, content is not English but i build on default Drupal, that mean everything is English, except content i write.

In some views, i'm using date and times formats to provide the time my content event will happen. But time&date provide by Drupal is English, like : Wednesday, December 28, 2016

So i need to translate it to my language. It is only thing i need to translate.

I try to follow official way, creat my language in Regional and language setting, enable Interface Translation, upload my language .po file from localize.drupal.org, change default language to my language, booom, date now show in my language very nice, but, everything messed up.

URL broken, title, desciption, tag, meta tag .... everthing become a mess. That mean i need to reset everything, what content not set language will need set, URL need to be update, .....

I mean why i need to do a ton of job and change a lot of thing in my site to do a just simple job : Change '*December*' to '*Tháng Mười Hai*'

So i wonder, there is someway easier to do that job? Keep my site simple, English by default.

I thinking about translate it by javascipt but it not good for SEO and it is a dirty way. Please help me.